# How to bind an ObservableCollection to TreeView (hierarchical)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I've the following TreeView:

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"  Grid.Row="3">

        <TreeViewItem Header="Section 4">
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Total:"  Width="150"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pool.Count}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Code" Width="150" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecretViewModel.Codes}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub-Section 4.1">
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfNames, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>

        <TreeViewItem Header="Section 5">
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Color:" Width="150" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Colors}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

How can I replace the Listbox and can bind the ObservableCollection to the TreeviewItem? It should look **hierarchical**.

I've tried to insert this code instead of the  with the TextBox, but that does not work:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListOfNames, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Please explain what do you want to display in TreeView and more about your datamodel.

Comment: Helped you out, no...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. You don't mean...

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Section 4">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Sub-Section 4.1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfNames,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</TreeViewItem>
```

[image]